# Retopology Texture bakes with seams

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, texture-baking, retopology

I am currently new here but I've been modeling for around three years. Recently I started working on a project that required me to go out of my comfort zone and create a humanoid figure. Since it needs to be animated, I retopologized for the first time. Now I want to bake the higher poly texture onto the lower poly model, but when I do, I get visible seams on all the UV seams.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a margin on the texture, but the edges are just sloppy, and having the margins does nothing.
[image]

why are the edges of the texture so dirty and how can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I would rather not since I dont want it stolen.

Comment: I understand but you could just share a small part of it  ;)

Comment: Actually, I was able to take it into ps and do content-aware fills around the edges and it worked just fine